# Mods breaking Sims 4: does it also happen if I don't update the game?

Tags: mods, the-sims-4

[Here](https://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/sims-4-broken-mods-find-fix/#:%7E:text=Typically%2C%20a%20mod%20will%20break,when%20a%20major%20update%20occurs.) it says

> Typically, a mod will break every time there is an update to The Sims
> 4. However, some mods are made to be more resilient and will only break when a major update occurs

Do the mods also break the game if I don't update Sims 4 after installing the mod?

Comment: Mods don't breaks the sims, the sims breaks mods when it updates. I've not found a way to _not_ update the sims -- even when i remain offline, the origin client requires me to go online every 30 days or so, triggering updates.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Have you tried marking the game files as "read-only"?